# Compare a list to a list of tuple to get another list

Tags: python, list

I am new to python so apologies for the naive question. I have a list

```
l1 = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

and another list of tuples

```
l2 = [(4,6), (6,8), (8,10)]
```

I want to output a list `l3` of size `l1` that compares the value of `l1` to the first co-ordinates of `l2` and stores the second co-ordinate if the first co-ordinate is found in `l1`, else stores 0.

output :

```
l3 = [0, 6, 8, 0, 10]
```

I tired to do a for loop like:

```
l3 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
   if l1[i] == l2[i][0]:
      l3.append(l2[i][1])
   else:
      l3.append(0)
```

but this doesn't work. It gives the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

which is obvious as `l2` is shorter than `l1`.

Comment: Will there ever be a case of multiple tuples in `l2` having the same first element?  If so, what's the rule there?

Comment: It looks like `l2` should be a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: @jedwards no it won't have multiple same first elements.

Comment: Well done on asking a sensible question with properly formatted code, input data,  required output *and* an error message. This is quite rare on stackoverflow. Please ask more questions like this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from `l2`:

```
l1 = [2,4,6,7,8] 
l2 =[(4,6),(6,8),(8,10)]
new_l2 = dict(l2)
l3 = [new_l2.get(i, 0) for i in l1]
```

Output:

```
l3 = [0,6,8,0,10]
```

Comment: Elegant solution, naive method would be using loop inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would always use [Ajax1234's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824660/6272142) instead, but I wanted to illustrate how I would approach it using a for-loop, as you intended:

```
l3 = []
for elem in l1:
    pairs = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == elem, l2))
    l3.append(pairs[0][1] if pairs else 0)
```

---

An alternate approach would be using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and a list comprehension instead of `filter()` and a for-loop. This one is far more efficient and readable:

```
l3 = [next((u[1] for u in l2 if u[0] == elem), 0) for elem in l1]
```

Comment: @Jenny I'm glad it helps! Note that I've added another approach using `next()`, which should be far more elegant than the previous one. Make sure to check that out too, as this function can be particularly useful in Python.